# Tableau. I can't find "pivot" in version 2023.3

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have problems finding the action to apply "pivot", I find it in the latest version 2023.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2VpF.png)

I already looked at different tab options, I also did what they say in the Tableau support videos, apparently it is outdated

Comment: Use Tableau Prep, its a cleaner approach

Answer (score 0):

The second last option in the menu should be Pivot.

Personally, I wouldn't be pivoting those 2 columns, but that's your choice.